# Access data model in VueJS with Cypress (application actions)

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I recently came across this blog post: [Stop using Page Objects and Start using App Actions](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/). It describes an approach where the application exposes its model so that Cypress can access it in order to setup certain states for testing.

**Example code from the link:**

```
// app.jsx code
var model = new app.TodoModel('react-todos');

if (window.Cypress) {
  window.model = model
}
```

I'd like to try this approach in my VueJS application but I'm struggling with how to expose "the model".

I'm aware that it's possible to expose the Vuex store as described here: [Exposing vuex store to Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/28/testing-vue-web-application-with-vuex-data-store-and-rest-backend/#store-testing) but I'd need access to the component's `data()`.

So, how could I expose e.g. `HelloWorld.data.message` for being accessible from Cypress?

[Demo application on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-cloud-vr3bw)

Would it be possible via [Options/Data API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vue is pretty good at providing it's internals for plugins, etc. Just `console.log()` to discover where the data sits at runtime.

For example, to ***read*** internal Vue data,

either from the **app** level (main.js)

```
const Vue = new Vue({...
if (window.Cypress) {
  window.Vue = Vue;
}
```

then in the test

```
cy.window().then(win => {
  const message = win.Vue.$children[0].$children[0].message; 
}
```

or from the **component** level

```
mounted() {
  if (window.Cypress) {
    window.HelloWorld = this;
  }
}
```

then in the test

```
cy.window().then(win => {
  const message = win.HelloWorld.message; 
}
```

But actions in the referenced article implies ***setting*** data, and in Vue that means you should use `Vue.set()` to maintain observability.

Since Vue is exposed on `this.$root`,

```
cy.window().then(win => {
  const component = win.HelloWorld;
  const Vue = component.$root;
  Vue.$set(component, 'message', newValue);
}
```

---

P.S. The need to use `Vue.set()` may go away in v3, since they are implementing observability via proxies - you may just be able to assign the value.

---

#### Experimental App Action for Vue HelloWorld component.

You could expose a setter within the Vue component in the mounted hook

```
mounted() {
  this.$root.setHelloWorldMessage = this.setMessage;
},
methods: {
  setMessage: function (newValue) {
    this.message = newValue;
  }
}
```

But now we are looking at a situation where the Cypress test is looking like another component of the app that needs access to state of the HelloWorld.

In this case the Vuex approach you referenced seems the cleaner way to handle things.

Comment: This works fine :-) I updated your answer as I had to use `Vue.$set()` instead of `Vue.set()`. Otherwise I get the error `Vue.set() is not a function`.

Comment: You mentioned accessing a component from the Vue instnace with `win.Vue.$children[0].$children[0]...`. Is there a way to "recursively find" a component by its name no matter where in the tree it is located?

Comment: Technically yes. The search should ideally be based on component name (which can be identified with `$vnode.tag` e.g 'vue-component-2-HelloWorld') + the property name, but then what about the situation with say buttons which would appear all over the app tree?

Comment: I think the principle of App Actions is to make the app test-friendly by adding methods to the app which can be used (perhaps exclusively) within tests. In a Vue context that means having methods on a component to update the data and also possibly exposing then on `$root`, see above potential example.