# Access JavaScript variables served by the website in test with cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I wondered if it was possible to get access to a variable which is served in JS by the page which I'm testing.

**Website serves Javascript:**

```
var varyingUrl  = 'www.google.com';
```

**A cypress test**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('closeAccount', () => {
    var url = varyingUrl;
    cy.request(url)
})
```

I'm almost certain this isn't possible but I thought I'd ask in case someone has found a way to gain access to these available javascript variables available to the dom using cypress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was initially found for a [similar Vue/Cypress question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62297240/7696704) answered by [@Richard Matsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4716245/richard-matsen) - His answer can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62306039/7696704)

Essentially, we just call the window with cypress then using the window, we'll access our variables.

Using the example above, you can get variables which are server is loaded via js source files:

#### Solution

**Your variable to get**

```
var varyingUrl  = 'www.google.com';
```

**The cypress code:**

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
    // use this area to code using the variable, prepending with "win." eg.
    cy.log(win.varyingUrl) // or console.log(win.varyingUrl)

})
```

**Console output:**

```
'www.google.com'
```

Comment: Assuming that the variable is a global variable, or is accessable through a global variable